# AADDC SLDAP Implementation

Tags: entra-id

I am new to Azure's Active Directory Service and it's abstraction is a little bit of a puzzle for me at the moment. What I am trying to do is to have all my AWS EC2 Servers (Linux) be authenticated via LDAP (for SSH Connection).

I have successfully setup the SLDAP, the Public IP Address is already generated and I have bind it to a FQDN (dc.mydomain.com). On my AWS EC2 Linux server, I installed sssd and realmd to be able to accomplish SSH AD Authentication.

Here is the ldap string I use that confirms sldap is working properly:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://directory.mydomain.com:636 -Z -d 5 -x -b "dc=mydomain,dc=com" -D "it@mydomain.com" -W
```

The command above gives all the info about the DN,CN,OU,DC listed on the Azure AD.

As I try to use PAM on CENTOS7, it seems like the `binddn` doesn't resolve to any `results()` -- for sure the `dn` I'm using exist as it's the one showing on the ldapsearch results.

Does MS Azure have restriction/limitation on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation states that there are limits for Azure AD DS with secure LDAP.

From the documentation, it only said that you can access the managed domain with secure LDAP over Internet. Also, it doesn't state that it can be used by application for authenticating against Azure AD.

As an alternative, instead of Azure AD DS with LDAPS, you may look into using Azure AD for Linux logins from link below. You even can find sample code from [here](https://github.com/bureado/aad-login).

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Open/Using-Azure-AD-for-Linux-logins

### UPDATE

It works by using Azure AD for SSH login on my RHEL 7.3. Followings are the step by step guide to make Azure AD work for Linux logins.

### Prerequisites

- An Azure AD directory has been created, and some users exist
- Node.js and npm are installed in the Linux VM
- A directory application has been created (native client type) and you have the Client ID
- Your PAM distribution has pam_exec.so

### User provisioning

You need to use the following command to add the Azure AD account, this ensures the user you'll be logging in with is visible by NSS.

```
sudo useradd -m <user>
```

### Installing

You can download the tarfile  from https://github.com/bureado/aad-login and:

```
sudo tar xzf aad-login_0.1.tar.gz -C /
cd /opt/aad-login
sudo npm install
```

### Configuring

1. Open /opt/aad-login/aad-login.js, and change the following items

> **var directory = '********.onmicrosoft.com';**    // The domain name of directory
>   **var clientid  = '****-****-*****-*****-**********';**    //The Client ID of the application registered in Azure AD
>   **authorityHostUrl : 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'**  //The latest URL of the endpoint

2. Open /etc/pam.d/sshd and add following rule

> auth  sufficient pam_exec.so  expose_authtok /usr/local/bin/aad-login

**Note:** For Utuntu, you need to add the rule in /etc/pam.d/common-auth

3. In CentOS 7.x (and other SELinux-enabled distros) you need to disable the policy by running following command:

   sudo setenforce 0

Comment: I tried using this. But it is giving me an error which I believe pertaining to the module itself. On that sample codes, I tried to manually login, based on the link on `aad-login.js` and it doesn't go through. I wonder if the endpoint is changed to something else (`login.windows.net`).

Comment: I can get it to work on my RHEL 7.3. You need to update the URL of endpoint to https://login.microsoftonline.com, also, the SELinux should be disabled. I have updated the previous reply, you can check it for more details.

Comment: When I run `node aad-login.js <username> <password>` via root, it gives me the AADDC details. However, trying to login via ssh, it gives me error.

---

`Jan 24 12:49:34 ip-172-30-0-184 sshd[17195]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=223-222-222-210.static.imsbiz.com  user=ldap-user`
`Jan 24 12:49:36 ip-172-30-0-184 sshd[17195]: Failed password for ldap-user from 223.222.222.210 port 54248 ssh2`

Comment: Did you add the following rule in /etc/pam.d/sshd correctly.`auth sufficient pam_exec.so expose_authtok /usr/local/bin/aad-login`. Is there any log messages same as below. `pam_exec(sshd:auth): /usr/local/bin/aad-login failed: exit code 139`. Also, please make sure the SELinux is disabled.

Comment: on the `/var/log/secure` it doesn't show any, that's why I tested the script if it work by manually triggering it as root and running the raw commands. On my box, before doing it manually, I can confirm that *SELinux is disabled*. The only thing that's different from your `env` from mine is that I am trying to run it  on Amazon Linux (which is a varient of CentOs). If you can confirm that it's working on your RHEL7, then, something on the OS level (specifically for Amazon Linux) is causing the issue.

Comment: You can try to add the rule to /etc/pam.d/system-auth, instead of /etc/pam.d/sshd. Also, I'll try AAD on CentOS7, and give you feedback later.

Comment: Yes, I did. Did it on both `sshd` and `system-auth` isolating the issue and it still doesn't do it. It keeps on flagging a *password* error -- which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I tried what is stated [here](http://superuser.com/questions/900417/pam-exec-so-doesnt-write-password-to-script-when-expose-authtok-is-enabled) and still not to get it running on Amazon Linux

Comment: I test it on CentOS7.3, and it works. I can get the related log message from /var/log/secure. By the way, have you ever run the command  `sudo npm install`?

Comment: Yes I have, made sure the module is there. I haven't gone back to this as I got sidetracks to other projects. But I'll keep you posted once I've get my hands on it once again. If it's working on CENTOS, it should be working on Amazon Linux (maybe needs some tweakings).

Comment: Still no lack for me on this. Though I can confirm that the login works as running the command in raw format gives all the details about the account. Command is `node aad-login.js <username> <password>`

Comment: Ok, I got it working! Amazon Linux has this default settings on everything inside `/etc/pam.d`. So from someone who's ain't that have much experience on PAM Auth, I have to read some of the docs to recognize the problem. Thanks Andy for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to hear that you find out the root cause.